# What do admissions like to see in online profiles?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

I have a website for my academic profile. The content include academic CV, a little bit about the research I have done, a technical computing related hobby of mine etc.

I intend to state the URL for this website on my academic CV for PhD applications.

**Questions**

1. Would the admission committee view the online profile of an applicant when considering his/her application?
2. If so, what kind of information would the admission committee like to see on it?

**(Edit) Additional Information**

I am applying to applied mathematics departments in the USA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Admissions committees are looking for **strong evidence of research potential**; that's what your web site should give.  At a minimum, your academic web site should have

- Your academic CV
- A list of publications and research projects, with download links.

You *may* want to include a copy of your research statement, but only if you don't tailor your statement to each department you apply to.

Keep it simple.  If your site looks too flashy, you may give the impression that you spend too much time fiddling with your web pages instead of doing research.  (Cough.)

Make sure *everything* that you post on your web site is polished and professional.  Proper spelling, grammar, notation, and technical language counts, just as it does in your research statement.

Finally, @aeismail is correct: Do not assume that admissions committees will look at your site; some will, some won't.  Your application must stand alone.  But if you mention any publications, independent projects, or other results in your statement, point the reader to your site.  *Even if nobody actually visits your site*, your willingness to display your work in public will work to your advantage.

Comment: I come across this "f your site looks too flashy, you may give the impression that you spend too much time fiddling with your web pages instead of doing research" sentiment a lot. What about if you run a blog, and make detailed/polished posts? Could that reflect negatively on you as not doing research? What is the blog has non-hidious theme and design?

Comment: There's a loooooong spectrum between "not hideous" and "too flashy", with "polished" somewhere in the middle.